# Formatter issue when language changed in device

Tags: ios, currency, swift4, numberformatter

I'm trying to get `float number` from `amount` string with out `currency symbol` like "100.00". Its working properly in English language. When language changed to German in device, its behaviour is getting changed. How can I achieve float value with out affecting by language change in device.

```
func getFloatNumberFromString(_ str: String) -> Float {
        guard let number = NumberFormatter().number(from: str) else {
            return 0.0
        }

        return number.floatValue
    }
```

another piece of below code to deal with it:

```
    func removeFormatAmount() -> Double {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            return formatter.number(from: self) as! Double? ?? 0
   }
```

When I use second method then the output is coming as 0.

Please let me know what am I missing or suggest me to deal with it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many European countries the decimal separator is a comma rather than a dot.

You could set the `Locale` of the formatter to a fixed value.

```
func float(from str: String) -> Float {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    guard let number = formatter.number(from: str) else {
        return 0.0
    }

    return number.floatValue
}
```

PS: I changed the signature to fit the Swift 3+ style

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to cast directly? Like this.

```
let floatString = "12.34"
let number = Double(floatString) ?? 0.0
```

Comment: sometimes the value may contain comma like 1,000.00 then how show I handle it?